# Applying list values to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of dictionaries that look like this:

```
final_list = [{'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}, {'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}, {'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}]
```

And I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
input_list = [['London', 'New York', 'San Francisco'], [8908081, 8398748, 883305]]
```

I'm trying to map the proper values from `input_list` to `final_list`, but I can't figure out how. I'd imagine it would be something like:

```
n = 0 
while n < len(final_list):
     for category in input_list:
          for section in final_list:
                # then here, somehow say 
                # for the nth item in each of the sections, update the value to nth item in category
                # then increment n
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
final_list = [{'city': c, 'population': p} for c, p in zip(*input_list)]
```

Here is the content of `final_list`:

```
[{'city': 'London', 'population': 8908081},
 {'city': 'New York', 'population': 8398748},
 {'city': 'San Francisco', 'population': 883305}]
```

You can do even something fancier by only using a function-based approach. This works with *any* number of keys you might need.

```
from itertools import cycle

keys = ('city', 'population')
final_list = list(map(dict, zip(cycle([keys]), zip(*input_list))))
```

Comment: Wow, that was a really clean way to do that, thank you!

Comment: I would go for `update` as `final_list` had been defined: `[d.update({"city":c,"population":p}) for d,c,p in zip(final_list, *input_list)]`

Answer (score 2):

Riccardo Bucco's solution will work, but if you want it to work with any categories (and not only city and population) this code will do it:

```py
final_list = [{'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}, {'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}, {'city': 'value', 'population': 'value'}]

input_list = [['London', 'New York', 'San Francisco'], [8908081, 8398748, 883305]]

for i in range(len(final_list)):
  for k in range(len(list(final_list[i].keys()))):
    final_list[i][list(final_list[i].keys())[k]] = input_list[k][i]

print(final_list)
```

Comment: note that `zip` works with multiple lists as well (if you're assuming `zip` only works with 2 lists)

Comment: I know, but then you will need to manually add the categories here: `{'city': c, 'population': p}`

Comment: I was just about to ask a follow-up comment about how I would make it more general, this site always manages to read my mind :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean. you mean the use of `keys()` instead of hard-coding them

Comment: Exactly, I think it is most of the times a better solution to make your code more general, in case you change something...